# MatLab: Weird display of logarithmic z-axis and bar3

Tags: matlab, histogram, matlab-figure, logarithm

I want to display a 3d histogram using `bar3`plot. Using linear scales with respect to x-, y-, and z-axis gives the following result:

[image: Plot with linear z-axis]

However, since the z-values have a very large interval I want to use a logarithmic z-axis such that the lower z-values are also visible. However, setting the z-axis to logarithmic with `set(gca, 'ZScale', 'log');` yields the following plot, which does not look good:

[image]

Is there some extra option I need to set or is it a known bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would bet you have 0s, NaNs or even negative values in your data. Could you give a small sample together with the corresponding plots?

Comment: You should check your `z-data`. E.g. using if-cases for checking for NaN's 0's and negative Values. Since `log(-x)= a +b*i` is complex number, `log(NaN)=NaN` and `log(0)=-infinity`. Not sure why matlab says the last part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly common problem with log axis in Matlab with non standard plotting functions or modifications to plots, eg [trying to use transparency with log axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622802)

### The Problem

The plot generated by [bar3](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html) requires the OpenGL renderer which [doesn't support logarithmic axis](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98079).

### The Solution

Mimic log axis by transforming data and setting tick marks / labels

the following creates the plot with log axis to get tick marks and lables,  clears the axis then starts again plotting the log of the data with transformed tick marks and labels.

```
bar3(Z);
set(gca,'Zscale','log')
ticks=get(gca,'Ztick');
ticklabel=str2num(get(gca,'ZtickLabel'));
set(gca,'Zscale','linear')
cla

bar3(log(Z));
set(gca,'Ztick',log(ticks));set(gca,'ZtickLabel',10.^ticklabel)
```

only the formatting of the tick labels is lost.

This method does not work well for values in the range  `0-1` with `bar3` as the plot is inverted and negative causes issues with `log` in either case further transforms would be required. however looking at the data in the plots given this should not be an issue.