# Transparent surface plot

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make my surf plot transparent. This is my input:

```
surf(A,B,C,...
'EdgeColor', 'none',...
'FaceColor','interp')
colormap jet
alpha(.1);
```

I do not understand why code above isn't working.

Comment: works for me... any errors? you could try setting using property value pairs directly in the call to surf e.g. `surf(A,B,C,'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor','interp','FaceAlpha',0.1)`

Comment: unfortunately that makes no difference. no errors either :( ...

Comment: oddly, when i click brush/select data it seems to become transparent - does that give any clues?

Comment: Sadly that is no clue to me, but there are some things worth checking. Could you in a new Matlab session (before attempting to run the above code) run `opengl('info')` and `ver('MATLAB')` and edit the output into to the question.  Also it a long shot but, on the off-chance something else is wrong, could you also run `get(gcf,'renderer')` after the above code, and the output is not OpenGL try running `set(gcf,'renderer','opengl')`

Comment: i can do this, but i think the problem may be due to the fact that i am using set(gca, 'zscale', 'log') to log one of the axes. when i don't do this, i get a transparent plot.

Comment: ok... ignore everything i've said, it is simply log scale and transparency are not compatible

Comment: yes, i just gathered this too. shame! thanks for your help

Comment: It is fixable... you can to mimic the log axis by plotting differently see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23826377/3115638) you will need to change calls to `bar3(Z)` to `surf(A,B,C)`, change the value of facea to 0.1 (facea being short hand for FaceAlpha), and finally run `set(gca,FaceColor','interp')`